# Make bootstrap div fade out when adding 'hidden' class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap for css and I need help in fading out a div when the class 'hidden' is toggled.

My site structure is pretty simple: there are 3 main container divs: search, wait and show. Essentially, show is the lowest positioned one, wait is on top of show and search is at the very top.

All I need is for search to fade out over 3 seconds when this Jquery event is fired:

```
    $('.search').toggleClass('hidden');
```

I don't want it to just instantly disappear. Same with the wait div. I have tried using

```
    $(".searchBar").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $('.searchBar').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
```

But it doesn't work. The fadeout/fadein don't seem to have any visible effect. Since the hidden class is already in bootstrap, I do not want to create another custom one; there's got to be a way to accomplish this.

Comment: Add opacity: 0; and a CSS transition to .hidden class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap hidden class is:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

You can easily achieve this:

```
$('.searchBar').toggle( "slow");
```

Comment: Ended up using this answer. Didn't exactly use the hidden class, but it seems like an acceptable workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this:

```
$(".searchBar").fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $('.searchBar').addClass('hidden').show(0);
});
```

Comment: I think you can actually remove `.show(0)`, here. Maybe this is an update?